# Magento 2 set filter from controller

Tags: magento2, grid, filter, uicomponent

I have created a module to push magento information to OroCRM for Magento 2. Each item is saved on a grid and pushed using cron tasks. All this is working fine. Now I have added an admin notification on the back-end to inform the user when errors are found. I have a link to the same grid on the notification. However I need to set a filter show only the items with errors (I have the IDs of them). Any ideas how to set a filter (not default) to an admin grid (Ui Component) from an action?

[image: Error Message on the admin view]